# Android ReCaptcha: Checkboxes are not shown

Tags: android, recaptcha

I use **Android SafetyNet ReCaptcha** to show the Google captcha in my Android app. The problem is that when I test it, the checkboxes are never shown. Instead, the captcha is well shown, and its progress bar is animated a little, and then it finishes without any error, confirming I'm a human. **This behavior is normal and there isn't any bug.**

**But. I would want to force the captcha, which seems to work well as I've described above, to show the checkboxes.** By "checkboxes", I mean *e.g.* "checkboxes showing pedestrian crossings that the human user must claim to recognize by checking". The official documentation doesn't explain how to do it: https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha#send-request

## Resources (documentation and StackOverflow)

- **Documentation : 1 link but unrelevant**

I've followed this documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha#send-request . However, it doesn't give any information about how to solve my problem.

- **StackOverflow : 1 question but unrelevant**

I haven't found any relevant question. I've not found, in fact, any question on how to implement ReCaptcha for Android, except a very short one (which doesn't provide any useful data to solve my problem).

## My implementation

*I'm going to show you how I've implemented their API ReCaptcha for Android (SafetyNet ReCaptcha) to help you to help me.*

### The process

1. My app's users can sign-up, sign-in, sign-out.
2. When a user starts my app, a splash screen appears. If the user isn't connected, he is invited to touch a button.

   2.1. If he touches the button, the ReCaptcha is started.

   ```
   2.1.1. If the ReCaptcha is successfully completed, then the user can sign-up and sign-in with his Google account (I use Google Firebase Auth and even AuthUI).

   2.1.2. Otherwise, nothing occurs : he'll have to re-try to complete ReCaptcha.
   ```

### Sources

#### SplashScreen.java (an `AppCompatActivity` class): The "onClick" event handler listening to the "touch" event on the button

In résumé: I attach the listener to the button. If the latter is clicked, thus, I call `verifyWithRecaptcha` in a (synchrone! and it's voluntary) `Executor`. Then I call the Google's servers to be sure the captcha has been completed by a humain being, not by a bot, thanks to my class `NetworkUseRecaptcha` which provides the `result` of the Google's servers.

```
    final Context that = this;
    button_splash_screen_recaptcha.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Executor executor = new Executor() {
                @Override
                public void execute(@NonNull Runnable command) {
                    command.run();
                }
            };

            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SafetyNet.getClient(that).verifyWithRecaptcha("PUBLIC KEY")
                            .addOnSuccessListener(executor,
                                    new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(final SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse response) {
                                            String userResponseToken = response.getTokenResult();
                                            if (!userResponseToken.isEmpty()) {
                                                String[] parameters = new String[2];
                                                parameters[0] = "SECRET KEY";
                                                parameters[1] = userResponseToken;
                                                new NetworkUseRecaptcha(new RecaptchaPostExecuteCallback() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onTaskCompleted(String result, boolean background_error) {
                                                        if(background_error) {
                                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                                public void run() {
                                                                    Toast.makeText(that,"Error N°2: Unable to check the captcha.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                            return;
                                                        }

                                                        try {
                                                            final JSONObject json_response = new JSONObject(result);
                                                            if(!json_response.isNull("success") && json_response.getBoolean("success")) {
                                                                final List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = ImmutableList.of(
                                                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()
                                                                );
                                                                startActivityForResult(
                                                                        AuthUI.getInstance()
                                                                                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                                                                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                                                                                .setAlwaysShowSignInMethodScreen(true)
                                                                                .setLogo(R.drawable.yellow_logo)
                                                                                .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                                                                                .build(),
                                                                        REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN
                                                                );

                                                            } else {
                                                                Toast.makeText(that,"Error N°4: Unable to check the captcha.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            }
                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                                public void run() {
                                                                    Toast.makeText(that,"Error N°3: Unable to check the captcha.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }).execute(parameters);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                            .addOnFailureListener(executor, new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    System.err.println(e);
                                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            Toast.makeText(that,"Error N°1: Unable to check the captcha.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

#### NetworkUseRecaptcha.java: My class that allows me to contact the Google's servers to verify the captcha

```
class NetworkUseRecaptcha extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final RecaptchaPostExecuteCallback post_execute_callback;
    private boolean background_error;

    NetworkUseRecaptcha(RecaptchaPostExecuteCallback post_execute_callback) {
        this.post_execute_callback = post_execute_callback;
        background_error = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[] parameters) {
        StringBuilder string_builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify");
            HttpsURLConnection https_url_connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            https_url_connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            https_url_connection.setDoOutput(false);
            https_url_connection.setUseCaches(false);

            OutputStream os = https_url_connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            writer.write("secret=" + parameters[0] + "&response=" + parameters[1]);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();

            InputStream input_stream = https_url_connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input_stream));
            String line;
            while((line = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null) {
                string_builder.append(line);
            }
            buffered_reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            background_error = true;
        }

        return string_builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        post_execute_callback.onTaskCompleted(result, background_error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetClient#verifyWithRecaptcha(java.lang.String): "If reCAPTCHA is confident that this is a real user on a real device it will return a token with no challenge. Otherwise it will provide a visual/audio challenge to attest the humanness of the user before returning a token."

So my wish is impossible to concretize...